# Escape single and double quotes in K8s Lifecycle hook

Tags: bash, kubernetes, trino

```
lifecycle:
  preStop:
    exec:
      command: ["sh", "-c", "curl -v  -X PUT -d '\"SHUTTING_DOWN\"'  http://localhost:8080/v1/info/state"]
```

I am expecting this will produce a curl url like

```
curl -v  -X PUT -d '"SHUTTING_DOWN"' http://localhost:8080/v1/info/state
```

How ever I am getting with extra single quotes surrounded ''"SHUTTING_DOWN"''

```
curl -v  -X PUT -d ''"SHUTTING_DOWN"'' http://localhost:8080/v1/info/state
```

Any pointers, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest getting rid of as many layers of quotes as you can.  In the original example you have a layer of quotes from YAML, plus a layer of quotes from the `sh -c` wrapper.  Since you need the HTTP PUT body itself to have both single and double quotes – you need to send the string `'"SHUTTING_DOWN"'` with both kinds of quotes over the wire – getting rid of as much quoting as you can is helpful.

In both the [shell](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02) and [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#73-flow-scalar-styles), the two kinds of quotes behave differently.  Backslash escaping only works in double-quoted strings and so you probably need that at the outer layer; then you need single quotes inside the double quotes; and then you need backslash-escaped double quotes inside that.

In YAML specifically the quotes around strings are usually optional, unless they're required to disambiguate things (forcing `'true'` or `'12345'`) to be strings.  This lets you get rid of one layer of quoting.  You also may find this slightly clearer if you use YAML *block style* with one list item on a line.

```yaml
command:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - curl -v -X PUT -d "'\"SHUTTING_DOWN\"'" http://localhost:8080/v1/info/state
```

I might even go one step further here, though.  You're not using environment variable expansion, multiple commands, or anything else that requires a shell.  That means you don't need the `sh -c` wrapper.  If you remove this, then the only layer of quoting you need is YAML quoting; you don't need to worry about embedding a shell-escaped string inside a YAML-quoted string.

You do need to make sure the quotes are handled correctly.  If the string begins with a `'` or `"` then YAML will parse it as a quoted string, and if not then [there are no escaping options in an unquoted string](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#733-plain-style).  So again you probably need to put the whole thing in a double-quoted string and backslash-escape the double quotes that are part of the value.

Remember that each word needs to go into a separate YAML list item.  `curl` like many commands will let you combine options and arguments, so you can have `-XPUT` as a single argument or `-X` and `PUT` as two separate arguments, but `-X PUT` as a single word will include the space as part of that word and confuse things.

```yaml
command:
  - curl
  - -v
  - -X
  - PUT
  - -d
  - "'\"SHUTTING_DOWN\"'"
  - http://localhost:8080/v1/info/state
```

Comment: Thanks David,
unfortunately, for the first approach, 
my command has a special liking of the additional single quote
i.e: **'"SHUTTING_DOWN"'**
The moment I Omit the single quote, my curl command started failing.
Unfortunately the second approach didn't turn as expected and throwing yaml errors i.e: _"did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character"_

Comment: What needs to be passed as the HTTP PUT body; does the string passed over the wire need to include single quotes outside double quotes around the string?

Comment: Yup, SHUTTING_DOWN has to be in both  single and double quotes in the same order.
**'"SHUTTING_DOWN"'**

Comment: Got it; I've updated the answer accordingly.  (At both the YAML and shell layers you probably need to put that string in double quotes and then escape the double quotes inside the string.)